# CIFIlter Apply to animationImages of UIImageView

Tags: swift, uiimageview, cifilter, glkview

Using CIFIlter I want to apply same filter to multiple images 
I have multiple **animationImages of UIImageView**

```
        let sepiaFilter = CIFilter(name:"CIColorControls")
  let brightness =  0.8

for  image in imageView.animationImages {

                guard let ciimage = CIImage(image: image) else { return }
                if  let newimage = self.sepiaFilter(ciimage, filter: filter, intensity:brightness )
                {

                    let cgImage:CGImage = ciImageCtx!.createCGImage(newimage, from: newimage.extent)!
                    let image:UIImage = UIImage.init(cgImage: cgImage)

                    newImages.append(image)
                }



            }
        }
 func sepiaFilter(_ input: CIImage,filter: CIFilter?, intensity: Double) -> CIImage?
{
    filter?.setValue(input, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    filter?.setValue(intensity, forKey: kCIInputBrightnessKey)
    return filter?.outputImage
}
```

So let me know what is best solution to apply **CIFilter to multiple images** ?

Using above for loop **CPU Usage** increased more than 100% so it is totally wrong way.

Is it possible animations in **GLKit View** ?
If yes let me provide deatils about it or Give best solution

```
**let cgImage:CGImage = ciImageCtx!.createCGImage(newimage, from: newimage.extent)!**
```

This line taking more CPU usage and time

Thanks.

Comment: First, **yes** you can use `GLView` for "real-time" changes to things. I greatly recommend that and can give you code/links to help. I have a couple of apps that use a custom `CIKernel` and animated "before/after" images on 5-7 source images. (Obviously it works with a timer, but they also show "real-time" edit changes to a single source image. My animation is only for showing what each filter can do.) I suggest (a) using `GLView` or `MTKView` instead of `UIImageView` - they use the GPU - and (2) using a **single** `CIContext` and (3) only using `CGImage` when needed.

Comment: BONUS! (Sorry couldn't stop myself.) If you do decide to go with `GLKView`, don't - as in DO NOT - use the simulator. Use a real device instead. What takes milliseconds on a device will take *several* seconds in the simulator. (And if you are using a `MTKView`? Metal doesn't (easily) run on a simulator.)